# Sorting mysql output on a different field with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I currently have the following code that outputs the count of unique occurrences of a name in a database, along with the names (for most common 100 names). The code works fine and the output looks like this:

```
Smith       71
Ryan        49
White       39
Brown       23
```

I want to repeat the list in a table next to that one with the output sorted in alphabetical order of name instead.

```
Smith       71             Brown     23
Ryan        49             Ryan      49
White       39             Smith     71
Brown       23             White     39
```

Is there any way of doing that as part of the mysql search please, or would I need to store the values in an array when I do the first loop, then sort and output the array?

If the latter, can anyone suggest efficient code to do it please.

```
 $query2 = "SELECT family_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM nametable 
            WHERE locationkey = $location
            GROUP BY family_name ORDER BY count DESC";
 $table2 = mysql_query($query2);
 $count2 = mysql_num_rows($table2);
 $tot = 0;
 echo '<table>';
 while ($tot < $count2 && $tot < 100) {
     $rec2 = mysql_fetch_array($table2);
     echo '<tr><td>',$rec2[0],'</td><td width="40">&nbsp;</td><td>',$rec2[1], '</td></tr>';
     $tot++;
 }
     echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the only way to do it that you haven't mentioned is to have two query calls, just with a different ORDER BY, but then you'd be able to use all of the same code (perhaps in a function) to draw the table.  Like put that entire chunk of code inside a function that takes a variable... $orderBy.  Then the only change you make is to the $query2 definition, just end it with "ORDER BY $orderBy";  Make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. I just thought the array option might be less of a load on the server because the database is about 750,000 records but I will typically be selecting maybe 500 records. Although the relevant fields are indexed.